# Dynamically pass parameters to function

Tags: python

I need to keep track of the number of times each function in a collection has been called. If a function is called more than `x` times within `n` seconds, my program needs to pause, after which the count for that function is reset.

My functions calls might look something like this:

`a(1)`

`b(1,param2=2, param3=3)`

`c(1,param3=3)`

My best idea is to have a wrapper function keep track of all of the limits. Something like

```
def wrapper(function, function_params,x,n):
    if not hasattr(wrapper, "function_dict"):
        wrapper.function_dict = {}
    if function not in wrapper.function_dict.keys():
        wrapper.function_dict[function] = {
            remaining = x, expires = time.time() + n
            }

    remaining = wrapper.function_dict[function]['remaining']
    expires = wrapper.function_dict[function]['expires']

    if remaining == 0:
        time.sleep(expires - time.time())
        wrapper.function_dict[function] = {
            remaining = x, expires = time.time() + n
            }

    results = ????? # call function, this is what I don't know how to do
        wrapper.function_dict[function]['remaining'] -= 1
```

My question is, how to I handle the parameters for the functions? I'm not sure how exactly to account for the fact that there might be a variable number of parameters, and that some might be named. For example, the function definition for `c` might be:

```
def c(param1,param2=2, param3=3):
    return param1 + param2 + param3
```

But I might need to call it with only `param1` and `param3`.

Do I have the right general approach? This feels like something I could accomplish with the `**` operator, but I'm stuck on how exactly to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a *decorator*, and use a *splat* operator to handle arbitrary arguments.

Example:

```
def pause_wrapper(x, n):
    def decorator(f):
        config = [x, time.time()+n]
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if config[0] == 0:
                time.sleep(config[1] - time.time())
                config = [x, time.time() + n]

            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

and usage:

```
@pause_wrapper(x, n)
def function(a, b, c):
    ...
```

---

The `*args` and `**kwargs` are informally called "splat" arguments. A function that takes `*args, **kwargs` receives all positional parameters in the tuple `args` and all keyword arguments in the dictionary `kwargs`. (You can have other arguments besides the splats, in which case the splats soak up all arguments not sent to named arguments).

Passing `*args` and `**kwargs` has the opposite effect, passing the contents of `args` as extra positional parameters, and `kwargs` as keyword parameters.

Using both allows you to handle any set of arguments, in or out, letting you do transparent wrapping (like this example).

Comment: ^this answer is the right one imho ...  (basically the same as mine but I used a class ...)

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll have to do a little more research on decorators, but this is a good push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

this is basically what decorators were made for

```
from collections import defaultdict
class counted:
     calls = defaultdict(int)
     def __init__(self,x,n):
         self.x = x
         self.n = n
     def __call__(self,fn,*args,**kwargs):
         results = fn(*args,**kwargs)
         calls[fn.__name__] += 1
         #do something with the count ...


 @counted(3,9)
 def functionWhatever(arg1,arg2,arg3,**kwargs):
      return "55"

 functionWhatever(1,2,3,something=5)
```

Comment: Wait, how does `__new__` on a decorator work? Pretty sure it should be `__call__`?