# Python decorators and scope

Tags: python

This a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195234/dynamically-pass-parameters-to-function/24195282#24195282).

I have two code snippets, one which works and one which does not. The following works:

```
def decorator(f):
    calls_left = [2]
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        if calls_left[0] == 0:
            print "limit reached, reseting"
            calls_left[0] -= 1
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    return inner

@decorator
def foo():
    print "Function called"

foo()
foo()
foo()
```

Produces:

```
Function called 
Function called
limit reached, reseting
Function called
```

However, if I change `calls_left` to a simpe integer, I get an error:

```
def decorator(f):
    calls_left = 2
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        if calls_left == 0:
            print "limit reached, reseting"
            calls_left -= 1
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    return inner

@decorator
def foo():
    print "Function called"

foo()



File "decorator_test.py", line 40, in <module>
    foo()
File "decorator_test.py", line 25, in inner
    if calls_left == 0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'calls_left' referenced before assignment
```

I understand that the list is mutable and the integer is not, but it seems like neither snippet should work. In the first case, my understanding is that `calls_left` is redefined when `foo` is called, so progressive incrementing shouldn't work. In the second case, I would expect `foo` to have access to `calls_left`.

Can someone explain this behavior, and the scoping issues surrounding my two `calls_left` objects?

Comment: The reference in the closure can't be redirected to another point. You can mutate the list, but integers are immutable, so incrementing or decrementing them in a closure will raise an error unless you declare it with nonlocal (only available in Python 3.)

Comment: @AaronHall you should post it as an answer!

Comment: Marked as a dupe, therefore cannot post further answers, but if you want to thank me, check out my other answers and review them. :)

Answer (score 0):

`calls_left` doesn't get redefined in the first example ... It only has a single element mutated.

In the second case, when python first looks at the functions code, it sees `calls_left` has an assignment to it, so it (wrongly) assumes that `calls_left` is in the current scope.  When you do `if calls_left == 0`, it tries to assign a new value to `calls_left` in the current scope (looking for `calls_left` in the current scope to calculate the new value).  When it doesn't find `calls_left` in the current scope, it raises the exception.

Comment: While your statement is obviously true, it doesn't explain why an error is raised on the second case. Care to explain ?

Comment: @alfasin -- updated.  Does that explain it better?

Comment: Thanks now it's clearer, thank you! the only thing that still bothers me is that the OP says he got the error on line `if calls_left == 0:` not on `calls_left -= 1`. Any ideas ?

Comment: @alfasin -- Good point.  For some reason, I always get the way this works wrong.  I've updated.  Actually, python thinks that `calls_left` is _local_ because it sees the assignment when it parses the function.  But then at the line `calls_left -= 1` (which is roughly `calls_left = calls_left - 1`), tries to find `calls_left` on the RHS of the equation in the local scope since it has an assignment to it in the function.

Comment: `calls_left == 0` does not assign a new value to calls_left. The only thing that makes sense to me is (and please correct me if  I misunderstood): on the first scan of the function, interpreter detects that there is an assignment to the variable `calls_left` (`calls_left -= 1`) and thus assumes it's a local variable and marks it as such. On the second pass (execution) it fails (on `calls_left == 0:`) cause there is no such local variable. While, when we declare `calls_left` as a list, we don't try to assign anything to it (only changing its items) - so the interpreter doesn't assume as local.

Comment: And the reason that the interpreter assumes its local is: according to the [spec](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces): "...all variables found outside of the innermost scope are read-only..."